# Do we have any thing related to OLE in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

We have a VB6 to VB.NET migrated project in which we have OLE control.Do we have any control in Vb.NET to replace the OLE?

Comment: What type of OLE are you performing?

Comment: I am performing Image Operation.

Comment: OLE is dead as a doornail, .NET has no support at all.  You can still use an ActiveX control in a Winforms project.  Use Aximp.exe to create the managed wrapper for it.